# How can I find a vector when multiplied by singular matrix?

Tags: matrices

I have the following equation:

$$Mv=MKu$$

Where $M$ is a $3\times3$ singular matrix, $K$ is a $3\times3$ invertible matrix, and $v$ is a known vector.

How can I find $u$?

If $M$ was invertible, I assume the solution would be $u:=K^{-1}v$.

Is there a solution if $M^{-1}$ doesn't exist?

Comment: Since $K$ is invertible, why can't you use $u=K^{-1}v$?  Since $M$ is not invertible, the only problem is that there will be many possible $u$'s.

Comment: Well, the thing is, I'm getting wrong results out of `u = K^-1v`, so my guess is I can't do that before dealing with M first. Also, the result vector `u` is actually the barycentric coordinates of a point, which is a unique combination.

Comment: Perhaps if you gave more details about what is going wrong, it would be clearer.  How are you getting wrong results?

Comment: Associativity :$(M K )(K^{-1}v)=M(K(K^{-1}v)=M((K K^{-1})v)=M(I v)=Mv.$

Comment: Michael Burr, I just posted another question explaining the exercise I'm dealing with. Can I post the link here? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1670736/determine-if-a-point-is-inside-a-subtriangle-by-its-barycentric-coordinates

Comment: user254665, thank you very much! Let me understand it and see if this actually helps me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $K$ is invertible, for a given $v$ the vector $u_1 = K^{-1}v$ solves the equation $$Mv = MKu_1,$$
as pointed out in the comments by Michael Burr and user254665: $MKu_0 = MKK^{-1}v = MIv = Mv$.

However, the choice of $u=u_1$ is not unique. Take any $v_0 \in \ker M$, i.e.  with $Mv_0 = 0$, and let $u_0 = K^{-1}v_0$   then we have for $u=u_0 + u_1$:

$$MKu = MKu_0 + MKu_1 = Mv_0 + Mv = 0 +  Mv.$$

Thus, the affine space $K^{-1}v + K^{-1}( \ker M)$ solves the equation.

Coversely, suppose $u$ solves the equation. We'd like to show that $u-K^{-1}v \in K^{-1}\ker M$, or equivalently $Ku-v \in \ker M$. We have indeed $$M(Ku - v)=MKu - Mv = Mv -Mv = 0.$$

In conclusion, **every solution** is of the form $$u=K^{-1}v + K^{-1}v_0$$ for some $v_0\in \ker M$. So if you are looking for a specific $u$, you're at least free in the choice of $v_0$.