# Determine if a point is inside a subtriangle by its barycentric coordinates

Tags: triangles, matrix-equations, barycentric-coordinates

[See this figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MW2KD.png)
[image]

ABC is a triangle. R is a point inside that triangle, specified by its barycentric coordinates. w is a scalar.

We mark the points B' and C' such that

- BB' == w and AB' == AB - w
- CC' == w and AC' == AC - w

My question is, given the three triangle sides, w and the barycentric coordinates of the point R, is there a way to determine if the point lies inside the subtriangle AB'C' or outside of it?

What I did so far is:

M = [A, B, C]
(each point is specified in a 3D space, so the matrix is of size 3x3)

The points of the inner triangle are A, B' and C', which I can also express in a matrix form:
[A, B', C'] = M * K

where K =
`[1,   p,   q
  0, 1-p,   0,
  0,   0, 1-q]`
p = w / AB
q = w / AC

I already know the barycentric coordinates of R, which I denote Rb below.

Thus M * Rb == M * K * Xb

Where Xb is a 3x1 vector holding the barycentric coordinates of the same point, expressed in terms of the inner triangle AB'C'.

Sadly, while K is invertible, M is not, thus I cannot express Xb as K^-1 * Rb.

Am I heading in the right direction or is there another/better solution (if there is a solution at all)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One basic approach to check if a point is inside a triangle is what's called the dot-product method ([the third method described here](http://totologic.blogspot.se/2014/01/accurate-point-in-triangle-test.html)). However this method relies somewhat on you having a right oriented coordinate system in two dimensions, but with barycentric coordinates we have three coordinates.

Now if we assume that we require the barycentric coordinates to add up to $1$ we would write the coordinates of a point $R$ as $R$ = $r_aA+r_bB+r_cC$ (avoiding having to divide by $r_a+r_b+r_c$ as required otherwise). This is awfully much like a normal coordinate system in three dimensions, and the requirement that the barycentric coordinates to add up to $1$ is the equation of a plane.

To mimic the dot-product method we need to construct a vector perpendicular to the oriented edges, but for a plane given in this form we know that we can form such a vector by forming the vector product with the normal to the plane. If $A$, $B$ and $C$ was an orthogonal base we would use the normal formula. However the fact that $R$ is inside the triangle is invariant under linear mapping - that is we can use the same formula anyway.

Now for a vector $(x,y,z)$ in that plane we form that normal by vector multiplying with a normal $(1,1,1)$ to the plane. That is

$$(x,y,z)\times(1,1,1) = (y-z , z-x , x-y)$$

So you use this to form the normals to $\overline{AB'}$, $\overline{B'C'}$ and $\overline{C'A}$ and then take the dot product of these with $\overline{AR}$, $\overline{B'R} and $\overline{C,R}$ respectively.

(note that when subtracting two points as in $\overline{AB'}$ you get a tripple, but these are not the barycentric coordinates for any point).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer! Can you please explain your solution in greater detail, because I'm a little bit confused about it. Where do I place the origin point and what "outside the plane" means?

Comment: I really don't understand the first paragraph. Can you point me to a resource where I can read more about these properties?

Comment: Basically what my aproach is doing is that it compares the orientation of the triangles $ABR$, $BCR$, $CAR$ and $ABC$ and checks that they have the same orientation (that is the order of the corners are either all clockwise or all counter-clockwise). I'll make the answer more clear soon.

Comment: [I made a quick scetch, does it illustrate your idea?](http://i.imgur.com/bvp2pTl.png) So you say, if I want to check if R is inside AB'C', I have to compare the volumes of the inner tetrahedrons? But how exactly?

Comment: By the way, I already know that R is inside the triangle ABC. I wonder how can I determine if it is inside AB'C' or outside of it.

Comment: I've updated the answer. The basic idea is the same - to interpret the barycentric coordinates as coordinates in a three dimensional space. But it seems to be easier (computational wise, and perhaps understanding-wise) to try to use the dot-product method instead of using volume products.